# How did Dr. Travnicek lose the Singularity Shifter?

Tags: wild-cards

In Wild Cards II: Aces High, Modular Man retrieves the singularity shifter for Dr. Travnicek. The next thing we see, it is in the possession of a nat gang, which is using it against its foes and police.

Was it ever explained how they got/stole it from the doctor? I've read the whole book and couldn't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *is* a little disjointed, but Travnicek is shown getting an eviction notice:

> “Goddamn the woman!” Travnicek said. His hand, which was holding a
>   letter, trembled with rage. “I’ve been evicted!” He brandished the
>   letter.

Later, the nat gang is shown stealing from a moving-van:

> It had been easy. While Flush and Sweat pretended to have a fight on
>   the pavement in front of the moving van, Ricky and Loco had simply
>   walked up to the van, liberated a pair of boxes apiece, and walked off
>   into the street. The tall geezer who was moving hadn’t even noticed
>   that some boxes were missing. Ricky patted himself on the back for the
>   idea.
>
> They didn’t get opportunities like this very often anymore. Nat turf
>   was getting smaller. Joker gangs like the Demon Princes were
>   swallowing more territory. How the hell could you fight something that
>   looked like a squid?

It's never explained directly, but the reader is left to conclude that the moving-van was Travnicek's since the gang finds ModMan's memory tapes as well as the singularity-shifter.

I think the author left this vague to break the "chain-of-custody", to show that nobody could connect the singularity-shifter to Travnicek.

Comment: Yes, that's it. I've just re-read the relevant chapters after seeing your answer. Thanks!